# How to go about implementing documentation\help into a WPF application?

Tags: c#, documentation

Due to the nature of the keywords, I find it difficult to easily google this. I want to implement a "help" item on the menu bar that will launch some basic documentation for the user to read, after I have written it. Are there any standards or libraries I should be aware about before diving into this aspect? The program incorporating the "help" functionality will be a C# WPF Desktop application.

Example from MS Word :
[image: Help button and window]

I'm sure they don't reinvent the wheel every time they use the help function, and I don't want to either. Where can I look to find something open source that is similar to this functionality and maybe some general guidelines on how to write help for non-technical and technical users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that following links should be useful for you. 
[Using F1 Help (CHM format) With WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928122/using-f1-help-chm-format-with-wpf) 
[how to create a chm help file for WPF Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417045/how-to-create-a-chm-help-file-for-wpf-application) 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce323cdb-5f9c-49d0-910e-81d2bba51d4d/context-sensitive-help-in-wpf?forum=wpf